# How to only allow letters to be pressed on in pygame?

Tags: input, python, pygame

I want the user to press on any letter of the alphabet; it should block the input from the rest of the keys. How can I do this using pygame?

```
Keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not exactly 'only allowing letters', but more 'only responding to letters'.

I'm not familiar with pygame, and my python is rusty, but according to the [documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html), you could do something like this:

```
press=pygame.key.get_pressed()
  for i in xrange( pygame.K_a, pygame.K_z + 1 ): 
    if press[i] == True:
      name=pygame.key.name(i) 
      # do something with the key
```

---

However, I must emphasize the documentation of [`get_keypressed`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed):

> Getting the list of pushed buttons with this function is not the proper way to handle text entry from the user. You have no way to know the order of keys pressed, and rapidly pushed keys can be completely unnoticed between two calls to pygame.key.get_pressed(). There is also no way to translate these pushed keys into a fully translated character value. See the pygame.KEYDOWN events on the event queue for this functionality.

Depending on what you exactly intend to do with these alphabet letters, you might want to use the [event](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) route instead.

Comment: It works in the sense that it doesn't take an input from any other key except the alphabet, however, when I print the name of the key pressed, I recieve this outcome:<built-in function name>

Comment: @AthR Are you sure you print the right thing?

Comment: I printed the variable name

Comment: I am soo sorry, I made a mistake. Instead of                         name=pygame.key.name(i), I wrote                    name=pygame.key.name. Thanks, it works now

Comment: @AthR Glad I could help :)

Comment: Can you please explain this line to me: if press[i]==1: Why is it 1?

Comment: @AthR In python, [`0` is considered `False` while all others numerical values are considered `True`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). It is a bad way to say `if press[i] == True`. I copy-pasted an example. You should really use `if press[i] == True:` :P

Comment: `if x == True` is less nice than just `if x`, similarly `if x == False` should be `if not x`